# What's causing the effect of salt in voltage arcs?

Tags: electricity, electrochemistry

I just came across this [video demonstrating that salt increases length of voltage arcs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8Ua8aAd2HM). There is no explanation which leaves me quite confused.

Does the salt decompose during the process?

Comment: The video says it's a salt (NaCl) solution placed on the electrode.  Salt in solution ionizes into Na+ and Cl- ions and mobile ions (ones that can move) improve conductivity because the ions themselves are charges that can be transported from one electrode to another.

Comment: Note that one could *test* this by looking at the chemistry of the deposits on the anode and cathode (assuming it's a DC arc, which may or may not be the case).

Comment: yes even in the microwave the plasma produced is heavily affected by the presence of sodium even just sodium contaminated glass container. Sodium seems to be a major issue as even a small contamination of it commonly causes yellow emission lines in visible spec

Answer (score 0):

SPECULATION:

> "Does the salt decompose during the process?"

I suspect that it does. The salt ionizes easily and the ions would migrate under the influence of the electric field. In so doing, they will further ionize the air they traverse, creating a stream of charge carriers. As the electrodes are pulled further apart, the energy available for ionization becomes smaller (the ions gain less energy per unit length as the voltage is constant but the distance increases, so the electric field strength goes down).

At a certain distance, the ions lose more energy during each collision than they gain during the acceleration due to the electric field - and then the arc extinguishes. So the arc is a result of the balance between ionization and recombination. The thing about having an electrolyte on one electrode only: there is no charged particle to recombine with. That probably really helps. If I'm right, then putting electrolyte on both electrodes would be less effective. Now I'm curious…

Incidentally - it sounded like this was an AC arc (there was a distinct low frequency buzzing) - but that doesn't jive with the above explanation unless the ions have a really long lifetime...

Comment: If you're right, does the salt decompose during the process?

Comment: Yes. That was my opening line: "I suspect that it does" - the answer to your question.

Comment: Damn, I must go to sleep.